# Java, save List of different Objects to SD Card

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I got this:

```
LinkedHashSet<Object> list = new LinkedHashSet<>();
list.add(new MyObject1());
list.add(new MyObject2());
list.add(new JSONObject());
list.add(new ObjectICannotEdit());
```

and I save to list to SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
final Gson gson = new Gson();
editor.putString(KEY, gson.toJson(list));
editor.commit();
```

I load like that:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String json = prefs.getString(KEY, null);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<LinkedHashSet<Object>>(){}.getType();
LinkedHashSet<Object> result = gson.fromJson(json, type);

for (Object t : result) {
    if(t instanceof MyObject1){
        //cant get here because t is a instance of LinkedTreeMap
    }
}
```

Can you tell how to keep the type of every object in my list while saving and loading?

Comment: You should/could serialize this instead of using JSON to persist the data in a file

Comment: i got a lot different objects that are not serialiazable by default

Comment: The values saved in a JSON format are eventually primitive type. And all primitive types are `Serializable`. So if you can save them with JSON, you can surely save them using serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to save your dataset with the use of `Serialization`.

Read more in the offical Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html (or just google a bit)

Make sure to `implement Serializable` in your custom classes!

e.g.

```
public class MyObject1 implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got a lot different objects that are not serialiazable by default.

Comment: A lot of java default classes are serialiazable by default. You have to set **each** class which is used in your `MyObject1` to implement Serializable if it is not native.